# how to find WSDL generated with java2wsdl

Tags: cxf, java2wsdl

I am using below command but i dont know where the WSDL file s created

```
java2ws -o Customer.wsdl -d C:\OMG -t http://customeroffer.manage.ws.usddomega.alu.com  -cp C:\omg\classes  com.alu.usddomega.ws.manage.customeroffer.ManageServicesCustomerOfferImpl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `-d <resource-directory>` which you have specified as **C:\OMG**

Comment: No even it is not htere with this command. Nothing is getting created

Comment: I think you also need to add the **-wsdl** argument.